# Equivalence between definitions of simple connectedness.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Wikipedia gives two definitions of simple connectedness:

1. A topological space $X$ is simply connected iff it is path-connected and any loop in $X$ can be contracted to a point.
2. A topological space $X$ is simply connected iff it is path-connected and any two paths with the same start-point and end-point are homotopic.

I do not see how these are equivalent. What is the connection between loops being contractable and and paths being homotopic? I am mostly looking for intuition here, as opposed to a formal proof.

By the way, I am aware of another definition: A topological space $X$ is simply connected iff its fundamental group is trivial. I would like to avoid that characterization here.

Comment: @MoisheKohan This is not a duplicate. That question is referring to the characterization of simple connectedness by triviality of the fundamental group. Here I am specifically avoiding that.

Comment: As I explained in my above comment, this question is NOT a duplicate of the other question. The other question uses trivial fundamental group as a definition of simple connectivity; here I am not.

Comment: Once one proves the above problem, only then one can start developing an intuition about *holes* -- not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The intuition to have here, is to think that $X$ has no holes in it. Both definitions make perfect sense from this point on.

Comment: Indeed that is a great intuition to have for the definition itself, but I am looking more for intuition for the *equivalence* of definitions 1 and 2.

Comment: If you want more mathematical insight into why they are indeed equivalent, take one loop and consider that the loop is a path and that the point at which it is contracted is also a path. Using the second definition you easily get the first one.

Comment: The 1) => 2) implication must certainly be less intuitive

Comment: I am guessing that taking any two paths, thanks to the connectedness of X you can construct a loop containing the two paths. Then using the first definition you can contract these two paths into a single point. Then you can (maybe with some efforts) construct a homotopy between the two paths.

Comment: And this homotopy $H$ will satisfy, $H(s,\frac{1}{2}) = p$ for any $s$ where $p \in X$  is the point at which the loop has been contracted.

Comment: Ah, I left out an important detail of the definition 2: we only consider paths with the same start-point and end-point.

Comment: Feel free to organize these thoughts into your answer and I will accept it. Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry, the fact that the end-points stay fixed, even when we apply the homotopy, is very important, and cannot be discarded as I mentioned earlier. I made a mistake.

Comment: The $2. \Longrightarrow 1$. is quite easy, but the $1.\Longrightarrow 2$., I can't get my head arround.

Comment: It might be that both definitions are not equivalent, but two separate definitions

Comment: I am sorry but  I don't see any value in the above *Answer*, none whatsoever. A *hole* is a very vague and general (multi-dimensional) notion which doesn't necessarily have to do anything with the 1-dimensional considerations.

Comment: The above theorem (OP's question) is too simple to seriously explain anything about *holes*. It's only a simple equivalence which takes advantage of elementary properties of square $[0;1]^2$, that's all.